# How do I remove the semi-colon symbol ';' with preg_match?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How to remove this character ';' with preg_march or other?

```
$urlt = 'tuto-rial.com;youtube.com;slideshare.net';
```

I want to remove ";" separating them into 3 links:

```
tuto-rial.com
youtube.com
slideshare.net
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the explode function like this:

```
<?php
    $newArray = explode(";", $urlt);
    foreach($newArray as $value)
    {
        echo $value . "<br /> \n";
    }
?>
```

Output:

```
tuto-rial.com
youtube.com
slideshare.net
```

Comment: her how to determine the value of "src" of some use in the same iFrame?
then the value is compared with the variable $ urlt?
his logic:
<pre>if (src = $ urlt) {
continue
else {}
return;
}</pre>

Comment: This question is very difficult to understand, but I understand the jist of it.

To get the "src" of an iframe you can use either of these methods:
`window.frames['iframe_name'].src`
`document.getElementById('iframe_id').src`


I have no clue what you're trying to do afterwards though, sorry

Comment: I'm sorry, I mean my question is how do I remove the ";" using the preg_match function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the PHP function "explode". See the php manual: [PHP explode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.explode.php)

Sample code:

```
$urlt = 'tuto-rial.com;youtube.com;slideshare.net'; 
$urls = explode(";", $urlt);
```

After that you will have the array "$urls" with your links in it.

Comment: her how to determine the value of "src" of some use in the same iFrame?
then the value is compared with the variable $ urlt?
his logic:
if (src = $ urlt) {
continue
else {}
return;
}

Answer (score 1):

No need to use regex for this simple task. Just use [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string into an array of string. See this code:

```
print_r(explode(';', "tuto-rial.com;youtube.com;slideshare.net"));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => tuto-rial.com
    [1] => youtube.com
    [2] => slideshare.net
)
```

Comment: her how to determine the value of "src" of some use in the same iFrame?
then the value is compared with the variable $ urlt?
his logic:
if (src = $ urlt) {
continue
else {}
return;
}

Comment: Not sure if understood your comment properly. But it appears to me that you're trying to extract `src` attribute of an `iframe`. It is better to look at DOM parser (http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) in php for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the result array.

```
$result = array_map('trim',array_filter(explode(';',$urlt)))
```